# PHP DOM: getElementsByTagName Returns all nodes with this name (although I'm inside a specific tag)

Tags: php, dom, getelementsbytagname

Im looking for an answer for DAYS! and I haven't found any.. :(
here is my XML sample:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Businesses>
    <Business NAME="Bus1">
    <DEAL ID="2">
    <title>My first Title</Title>
</DEAL>
    <DEAL ID="4">
    <title>My Second Title</Title>
</DEAL>
    </Business>
    <Business NAME="Bus2">
    <DEAL ID="2">
    <title>My 2nd Title</Title>
</DEAL>
    <DEAL ID="5">
    <title>My last Title</Title>
</DEAL>
    </Business>
    <Businesses>
```

How can i parse this xml one business by one?? Here is my code:

```
<?php 
  $doc = new domDocument();
  $doc->load("MyXML.xml"); //(The XML Above)
    $Businesses = $doc->documentElement;
    $ebus = $Businesses->childNodes;
    foreach ($ebus as $business) {

     if ($business instanceof domElement) {
     $busname=$business->getAttribute('NAME');
    $shelves = $Businesses->getElementsByTagName("DEAL"); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM

  foreach ($shelves as $deal) {

//Here i have all of the Businesses (I need to present only the first "NAME='Bus1'") for the first iteration! and so on..
}}}
?>
```

The issue is that "getElementsByTagName" bring all "DEAL" nodes althoug I'm inside foreach of the first business!!

I Tried:
$shelves = $Businesses->childNodes; // But it's Not Correct

Thank you for your Help!!

Comment: The obvious problem is that you are not closing your `DEAL` elements. Try it with them closed: `<DEAL ID="5" />`.

Comment: i wrote it by mistake Here without "</DEAL>" (close tag), In the original i do have it closed.. Waiting for more ideas :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling it on `$Businesses` which is `documentElement`. You assigned it at the start:

```
$Businesses = $doc->documentElement;
```

Try this:

```
$shelves = $business->getElementsByTagName("DEAL");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! you wrote exactly what i did (look inside my code), the problem is that it gives me all the "DEAL" nodes (I need it relatively the for each iteration) Thanks!

Comment: @user1542680 if there is a problem, let me know. If there is no problem, you should accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side of this answer. This way others know your issue has been resolved ... and we both get reputation points ;P

Comment: @user1542680 I didn't write what you have in your question. Look more carefully. Your question has `$Businesses->getElementsByTagName("DEAL");` My answer has `$business->getElementsByTagName("DEAL");`. You have `$Businesses`. I have `$business`. Do you see the difference?

Comment: WOW!! silly me :~) you are so right! so small mistake! you are the best! Thank you so much!!

Comment: I choose YES for "Is this asnser help you" is this the way to accept it? (Im New here)

Comment: @user1542680 you just click the checkmark image on the left of this answer, just below the score. Here's more help http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work